# Identifying and removing null characters in UNIX

Tags: unix, shell, null, special-characters

I have a text file containing unwanted null characters (ASCII NUL, `\0`). When I try to view it in `vi` I see `^@` symbols, interleaved in normal text. How can I:

1. Identify which lines in the file contain null characters? I have tried grepping for `\0` and `\x0`, but this did not work.
2. Remove the null characters? Running `strings` on the file cleaned it up, but I'm just wondering if this is the best way?

Comment: This kind of question probably belongs to SuperUser.com

Comment: In fact, this question is on superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-ths-symbol-with-vim

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I’d use `tr`:

```
tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls
```

*If you are wondering if input redirection in the middle of the command arguments works, it does. Most shells will recognize and deal with I/O redirection (`<`, `>`, …) anywhere in the command line, actually.*

Comment: and a "diff file-with-nulls file-without-nulls" should show me which lines had null characters? It brings back a lot more than expected.

Comment: Actually, I believe it should be `tr -d '\000' < file-with-nulls > file-without-nulls` since `<` is part of the shell pipe functionality and not `tr`.

Comment: Most shells will recognize & deal with < or > anywhere in the argument string, actually.  Surprised me too.

Comment: +1 For usage of input redirection instead of `cat |`. A fine, clean solution and it solved my problem.

Comment: This is an order of magnitude slower than `sed` for me

Comment: @diachedelic that's pretty interesting. I wonder what's behind that; buffering?

Comment: @Pointy I have no idea how the internals of either tool work, so I can't hazard a guess

Comment: @Pointy Is there a reason you use '\000' instead of '\0'? On the surface they seem to have the same effect

Comment: @HaroldFischer I don't recall why I wrote it that way 8 years ago I'm afraid :)

Comment: @Pointy '\000' is used in lieu of '\0' in the POSIX opengroup specification for tr. That is a good reason to prefer it

Comment: @HaroldFischer well I'm not sure what you're trying to do; if you want to see if  file has any nulls in it you could use `wc` to compare the size of the file pre-filtering and post-filtering. In a Unicode world it's generally a better idea to be prepared for non-ASCII characters than to worry about them.

Comment: @Pointy I do apologize, that question was meant for someone else

Comment: I manage to detect nulls using `grep -Poa '\000'` and using `wc`.  Seems easier and more direct / less error-prone.

Comment: @Pysis I'm glad that works for you, but I'm not sure what's less "error-prone" about it.

Comment: I can identify nulls more exactly matched to the content rather than aggregate file size.  I guess if we are replacing all nulls then maybe that's less of a problem.  Grepping just gives a more focused approach that I was trying to mention.

Comment: This is an extra-good answer for the description of the file redirects. That has the potential to make things so much clearer!

Comment: How can we automate the process, the moment multiple files arrived, remove its null characters ?

Answer (score 89):

Use the following sed command for removing the null characters in a file.

```
sed -i 's/\x0//g' null.txt
```

this solution edits the file in place, important if the file is still being used. passing -i'ext' creates a backup of the original file with 'ext' suffix added.

Comment: Note: In FreeBSD (and I believe also Mac OS X), `sed -i` *requires* an extension in the next argument, but it may be empty. In those systems, add a `''`, as in: `sed -i '' 's/\x0//g "$FILE"`.

Comment: This is an order of magnitude faster than `tr` for me

Comment: For me, using Git for Windows and `$ sed --version` -> `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`, I had to use the following invocation to get a backup file called `example.csv.bak`: `sed -i.bak 's/\x0//g' example.csv`

Comment: @TimČas you did it great, just missed one ' so it should be sed -i '' 's/\x0//g' some_file.xml

Comment: On mac this only did the first null character and not all of them.  `gsed` did work to do all of them.

Comment: Is `sed -i '/\x0/d' null.txt` a valid alternative? Maybe more elegant

Answer (score 23):

A large number of unwanted NUL characters, say one every other byte, indicates that the file is encoded in UTF-16 and that you should use `iconv` to convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: I ran out of disk space while my application was logging. This resulting in these characters.

Comment: For example, it works using this command: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 file`.

Answer (score 10):

I discovered the following, which prints out which lines, if any, have null characters:

```
perl -ne '/\000/ and print;' file-with-nulls
```

Also, an octal dump can tell you if there are nulls:

```
od file-with-nulls | grep ' 000'
```

Comment: for me only 'od -to1 ..' had the desired behaviout otherwise 2 bytes were put out like '001002'. Seems somehow like default settings or implementation of od have changed over time.

Answer (score 6):

If the lines in the file end with \r\n\000 then what works is to delete the \n\000 then replace the \r with \n.

```
tr -d '\n\000' <infile | tr '\r' '\n' >outfile
```

Comment: PS. If you find yourself in a Windows DOS shell, you can get the GNU/win32 versions of Unix commands from Sourceforge.net. I use them all the time.  Check out "od" the octal dump command for analysing what's in a file...

Answer (score 3):

Here is example how to remove NULL characters using `ex` (in-place):

```
ex -s +"%s/\%x00//g" -cwq nulls.txt
```

and for multiple files:

```
ex -s +'bufdo!%s/\%x00//g' -cxa *.txt
```

<sup>For recursivity, you may use [globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) `**/*.txt` (if it is supported by your shell).</sup>

Useful for scripting since `sed`  and its `-i` parameter is a non-standard BSD extension.

See also: [How to check if the file is a binary file and read all the files which are not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16760378/55075)

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
recode UTF-16..UTF-8 <filename>
```

to get rid of zeroes in file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error with:

```
import codecs as cd
f=cd.open(filePath,'r','ISO-8859-1')
```

I solved the problem by changing the encoding to `utf-16`

```
f=cd.open(filePath,'r','utf-16')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove trailing null character at the end of a PDF file using PHP, . This is independent of OS**

This script uses PHP to remove a trailing NULL value at the end of a binary file, solving a crashing issue that was triggered by the NULL value.  You can edit this script to remove all NULL characters, but seeing it done once will help you understand how this works.

*Backstory*
We were receiving PDF's from a 3rd party that we needed to upload to our system using a PDF library.  In the files being sent to us, there was a null value that was sometimes being appended to the PDF file.  When our system processed these files, files that had the trailing NULL value caused the system to crash.

Originally we were using sed but sed behaves differently on Macs and Linux machines. We needed a platform independent method to extract the trailing null value.  Php was the best option.  Also, it was a PHP application so it made sense :)

This script performs the following operation:

Take the binary file, convert it to HEX (binary files don't like exploding by new lines or carriage returns), explode the string using carriage return as the delimiter, pop the last member of the array if the value is null, implode the array using carriage return, process the file.

```
//In this case we are getting the file as a string from another application. 
// We use this line to get a sample bad file.
$fd = file_get_contents($filename);

//We trim leading and tailing whitespace and convert the string into hex
$bin2hex = trim(bin2hex($fd));

//We create an array using carriage return as the delminiter
$bin2hex_ex = explode('0d0a', $bin2hex);

//look at the last element.  if the last element is equal to 00 we pop it off
$end = end($bin2hex_ex);
if($end === '00') {
   array_pop($bin2hex_ex);
}

//we implode the array using carriage return as the glue
$bin2hex = implode('0d0a', $bin2hex_ex);

//the new string no longer has the null character at the EOF
$fd = hex2bin($bin2hex);
```