# Replacing the null character ^@ in a flat file

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a flat file generated from someone else's software. They insert the null character ^@ in certain positions of the file. I wish to replace them with something else like -9. How do I search and replace this character efficiently in terminal on Mac OS X?

Thanks.

There is another post addressing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix) in linux.

Answer (score 8):

(To maintain a SO tradition of proposing multiple answers with different tools for shell scripting questions):

With `tr`:

```
tr -d '\0'
```

Comment: Do you know the mac osx solution to this?

Comment: This works fine on osx too. +1 for maintaining SO traditions :)

Comment: I do not understand. So this will replace all null characters with a space, correct? But what if I wanted another string value?

Comment: No, it will delete the character, if you want to replace it with a particular character (say X), you can use `tr '\0' 'X'`, `sed` is better for replacing strings with strings.

Comment: `tr -d '\0'` will remove null characters altogether. For replacing with any string you want, take a `sed` solution. For replacing with another *single character*, you can also use something like `tr '\0' '_'`.

Comment: When processing binary files on macOS, use `LC_ALL=C tr -d '\0'` to avoid `tr: Illegal byte sequence`

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\x0/-9/g' filename > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually works well like the other post said. I realized now that I was trying this command on mac osx and that is why I still had issues. I reframed my question. Do you know the answer to this one?

Comment: Unfortunately on OSX 10.9.4 this is not the case. `printf "\1\0\1" | sed 's/\x0/-9/g' | hexdump` will still yield: `0000000 01 00 01 0a
0000004`. Version information is not in `/usr/bin/sed`, but apparently it's a BSD build from 2005. You can try to install GNU sed instead.