# Removing null bytes inline from file on OS X

Tags: macos, sed, byte

I have a set of files which have null bytes roughly at every second byte slot. Further, they have the byte sequence FF FE at the beginning, which needs to be removed. I was given the files (they are actually router configuration files, so plain text), and I have no idea how those bytes got in there. However, the file looks like this, which I found for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/287997/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-null-bytes) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881821/replacing-the-null-character-in-a-flat-file), :

```
FF FE 65 00 6E 00 61 00 62 6C 00 6C 65 00 0D 00
0A 00 63 00 6F 00 6E 00 66 00 69 00 37 00 75 00
72 00 65 00 20 00 74 00 65 00 72 00 6D 00 69 00
```

Think you can imagine how it goes on. I tried various things to remove the null bytes and the first 2 bytes as well:

- `sed -i.bak 's/\x00//g' R2.txt` does nothing.
- `LC_ALL=C sed -i.bak 's/\x00//g' R2.txt` does nothing.
- `LC_ALL=C tr < R2.txt -d '\000' > R2-test.txt` works, but is not in line.
- `LC_ALL=C sed -i.bak $'s/\x00//g' R2.txt` complains about `sed: 1: "s/": unterminated substitute pattern`

So... my question is, how to remove the null bytes the first two bytes (FF FE) from this file, inline, on OSX?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please open the file in vi and tell me what you are seeing "check for this sign  ^@ ". also you can do :set list to show all invisible characters.

Comment: also see suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix

Comment: Interestingly, vi does show no such characters. It shows ^M at the end of every line, which however does not explain the problem. vi however shows [converted] at the bottom.

Comment: first thing to do =>>  open the file in vi(m) and do :%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>/\r/g  so that you can get ride of windows carriage return to a *nix ones .

Comment: is your file showing as a one line

Comment: No, its not, there are newlines in between. Interestingly, on a Debian system, the sed examples work great.

Comment: soemone suggested : A large number of unwanted NUL characters, say one every other byte, indicates that the file is encoded in UTF-16 and that you should use iconv to convert it to UTF-8. so you may want to run the file through iconv.

Comment: Interesting idea. `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 R3.txt` results in `iconv: R3.txt:1:0: cannot convert`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124070/discussion-between-z-and-waza-ari).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you said " null bytes roughly at every second byte slot". This is a clear indication of the file being encoded with "charset=utf-16le" and you will need to convert it to utf-8 , ascii ..etc. try something like the below:

```
iconv -f "current-encoding"  -t "desired-encoding" infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help in chat, it was actually utf-16le. On OS X, I was not able to use iconv to convert the file. It worked using Debian, though.