# How to delete <0x00> characters in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: replace, sublimetext3

**Problem**

So I have this large text file which contains `<0x00>` characters (see picture below).

[image: Sublime Text 3 with <0x00> including replace option]

As you can see on the picture above, I have tryed to remove those characters with a regular expression `\x00`. Besides that, I have also tryed `\0` and `\00` with no success.

However, when I try to replace these characters in Sublime Text, a pop-up shows that these `<0x00>` characters indeed have been found (see picture below), so far so good.

[image: occurrences found]

Unfortunately, when I click the "replace" button the characters are not replaced.

**Question**

How can I get rid of these `<0x00>` characters?

*p.s. It is important to mention that I cannot do a search on "0" since this text file contains zero's, which I would like to remain.*

## Progress update #1

I have managed to copy a <0x00> char into the "find" search box (see picture below).

However, even when I try to replace this character with an empty character inside the text file no changes occur unfortunately.

[image: progress update 1]

## Progress update #2 (solution)

Without the helping hand of @00 I wouldn't find the answer to this problem, thank you!

**Explanation**

The file was encoded in UTF-16, but I assumed it was UTF-8. The file was opened in *BOM* UTF-8, which was exactly the reason why I was not able to delete the `<0x00>` (NUL) characters in Sublime Text 3.

**Solution**

Execute in 'bash' or in a 'terminal' the following command:

`sed -i 's/\x0//g' [textfile_name].txt`

Comment: Are those literally `<0x00>` or just markers denoting ␀ characters?

Comment: @00 I am not sure if I am right, but I do think that they are markers, since they are grayed out. However, when I click on such a char it selects the whole character, instead of just a "single" char of `<0x00>`.

Comment: It sounds like they are NULL's. Your file must have been corrupted. Unfortunately if the `\0` regex doesn't seem to be working you may have to get creative and use an external program to remove the, or pull from backup / source control

Comment: @00 I am sure now that they are NULL's, since 0x00 in hex denotes NULL. However, you say that my file may be corrupted. How can it be that I can replace "regular" text for e.g. the word "english" to "spanish", for some strange reason this is possible, but replacing `<0x00>` is not?

Comment: I've managed to get a find / replace to work and wrote it up in an answer. Try a regex of `\0` again

Comment: @Kamuffel - not only does your solution not work for me, but it doesn't indicate how one might approach this in a file with variances from your original use case.  For example the characters `<0x0c>` `<0x18>` need to be identified individually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I've tried this out myself and it seems that a regular expressions will work. Make sure you have the regex option selection (highlighted in image) and use a regex of `\0`:

[image: Sublime]

Now just make sure you have nothing in the replace filed and hit Replace All. The NUL characters should be gone.

**NOTE**

While reading around, it seems that you have a NUL after every other character which might indicate that the file is actually UTF-16 (and if this is the case, you **do not** want to remove them) and would need to be reloaded as such. If switching to UTF-16 and my above solution do not work, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identfiying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix) thread may be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your solution didn't work indeed. However, you did mention that the file is UTF-16, which is true! Thanks for noting that and referring to the other thread, which contained the solution I needed.

I got it fixed with the following command: `sed -i 's/\x0//g' [textfile_name].txt`

Comment: No problem, happy to have helped!

Comment: @Kamuffel - this solution worked for me and is the appropriate answer per your question.  Please mark correct.

Comment: Hey, 
I don't know, if this changed with a newer version of Sublime, but I had to mark RegExp search, like you explained and then look for `\00` or respectively `\01`, etc.
Searching for `\0` did not work for me.

Comment: btw, can anyone explain what this is...? and what do we call it? "weird characters in my text file" isn't enough...

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen see the note about encoding, its likely OP was opening a UTF-16 encoded file as something else