# Installing packages through PyCharm yields "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I've used PyCharm's package installer on other machines with no problem, but on this machine (Windows, if it matters) every time I hit the "install package" button, it fails.  Here's what I get when I ask for details:

```
Executed command:

pip install chess

Error occurred:

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 145, in main
    do_install(pkgs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 59, in do_install
    run_pip(['install'] + pkgs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 201, in run_module
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

At first I thought it was an encoding problem, so I switched my encoding to UTF-8 for everything, which briefly made PyCharm stop graying-out my "import chess" statements, but as soon as I went back into the menu and tried to install it the same problem occurred. This is also not a problem specifically with chess, because I'm having the same issue with pandas.

I'm using PyCharm community edition (originally 2017, but I reinstalled while trying to fix this problem, so now it's 2019). The project interpreter is Python 3.5.3rc1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with your PyCharm, but with the source code of the module, you are trying to install.
According to PyPi, it is this [one](https://github.com/doismellburning/chess), and it has been updated last time 7 years ago.

You could download it yourself and fix the problem with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix/2399817#2399817).

Answer (score 0):

If you also have problem to install other packages with PyCharm, have you tried using command prompt to install them?
`pip install chess`

Comment: Good suggestion but the person mentions that he tried that