# value error: source code string cannot contain null bytes in import numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[image]
I installed package numpy,pandas, and I tried to import it to my project,but unfortunately I received the
error: "value error: source code string cannot contain null bytes"
i don't have same problem with other package.How should i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you check either numpy is in your PYTHONPATH ? Try to run the python code in terminal / console.

Comment: Looks like you have null characters in your python file, check this SO thread to remove null chars from your file and then try again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix/2399817#2399817