# Null character removal in Unix file

Tags: unix

I have two null characters continuously, I need to replace the two null character with single space. Any command to help here ?  (Ideally I need to delete the two null character and add one space character)

Comment: have you tried anything? where did you get stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying and removing null characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix)