# unix2dos command failed because of ^@ symbol present in the file

Tags: unix, newline, null-character

I'm facing below issue when performing unix2dos conversion

```
unix2dos: Binary symbol found at line 166
unix2dos: Skipping binary file Sample.txt
```

I can find `^@` characters in the file.

I can do `-f` which is force conversion of binary files

Any idea apart from this?

I am able to replace the characters using vi, but not with the script.
Need to handle in the script, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A ^@ is a null character. I assume your working on a Unix/Linux platform.  Perhaps this answer may help [identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix)

More information about the null character can be found at [Wikie entry on null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)